# Modern objective C syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

As we know in WWDC 2012 Apple has provided Modern Objective C literals/syntax  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405n

I know we can use Refactor option to convert our code to modern objective C. (Xcode -> Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to modern Objective C).

Now my question is, can we check through any script whether project code has used modern objective C syntax or not explicitly?

As many of us know, we can convert "TODO", "FIX ME" into warnings by below script

```
 KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
  find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-      filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

In same manner I want to put warnings if modern objective C syntax are missing in my code so that I can refactor it!

Comment: The frequent used thing is `array[index]`..you can check for it.

Comment: You mean to say for each guidelines, we need to put syntax check?  Is there any optimised way?

Comment: I dont have any idea. But why you need to check? If you use new-syntax in old only then it wont compile, for other case it has no issue.

Comment: Yes you r right. If we use old syntax, it will compile. But According to me it will not be good practice. So If we able to put custom warning it will help to force to use new syntax.

Comment: **NO** that is nothing to do with application design, that is your convention.... you can direct your team not to use. But what in 2014? again a new change!!! So every year you need to change. Even all the api's after deprecation keeps on working....

Comment: According to me we should use updated syntax always. No need to change previous code but whenever we write we should. We need try to avoid deprecated methods. Yes if they done changes in 2014 again, we need to follow if we are start our app developing in 2014.i.e whatever is new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So look at NSArray and NSDictionary and tally all methods that the modern syntax replaces (ie objectAtIndex), and search for those. You may get some false matches.

Comment: Yes.This may be one of way to put checks for each point...  thanks David